# Powershell For each Write-EventLog

Tags: powershell

In my code I have a for-each loop, which writes a line to the event viewer log - this is fine for small runs but on larger runs where "each" is a large number its too many events. How can I only write the log entry after every 10'th pass through the loop or maybe time based?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the remainder operator `%` (sometimes referred to as the [*modulus* or *modulo* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.3#long-description)) to only do something on every `n`'th iteration:

```
$loopCounter = 0

Get-LargeNumberOfItems |ForEach-Object {
  if(++$loopCounter % 10 -eq 1){
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TonysEventSource -EventId 123 -Message "We're on the ${loopCounter}th iteration now..."
  }

  # do actual processing of $_
}
```

This will write to the event log on the first iteration, the eleventh, the twentyfirst etc., because the remainder of 1, 11 and 21 divided by 10 is 1 in each case, thus satisfying `++$loopCounter % 10 -eq 1`

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it works ... any issue using this for a while loop too ?